# number of I/O dispatchers in apache http async client

Tags: asynchronous, io, apache-httpclient-4.x, nonblocking

I am using Apache HTTP async client for making http requests (by consuming data from Kafka bus) and handle response in callbacks.

I found some interesting behaviors of the callbacks in my log and would like to figure out hwy it is like this.

Here is the partial of the code (consuming data from kafka and make http request):

```
    while (true) {
        ConsumerRecords<String, MyMessage> records = kafkaConsumer.poll(1000);
        if (records.isEmpty()) {
            logger.info("Polling Empty ....");
            continue;
        }

        int numberOfRecords = records.count();
        final CountDownLatch batchLatch = new CountDownLatch(numberOfRecords);
        for (ConsumerRecord<String, MyMessage> record: records) {
            final HttpPost request = new HttpPost(endpoint);
            // set headers
            // set entity
            request.setEntity(messageToEntity(record.value()));
            httpClient.execute(request, someCallback);
        }

        batchLatch.await();
        kafkaConsumer.commitAsync();
    }
```

And here is the example code of the callback:

```
public class SomeCallback {
    // ...
    @Override
    public void completed(final HttpResponse response) {
        // do something
        logger.info("{} - blablabla", status, ...);
        latch.countDown();
    }

    @Override
    public void failed(final Exception ex) {
        // do something
        logger.error("{} - blablabla", FAILED, ..., ex);
        latch.countDown();
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelled() {
        // do something
        logger.error("{} - blablabla!", CANCELLED, ...);
        latch.countDown();
    }
}
```

So the situation is, at some point of time, I started the program and it is starting consuming data from kafka. The max number of records per polling is 500.

And because there are already many unconsumed data on Kafka, the program faced a high throughput.

Now, the log looks like this:

```
[INFO ] 2018-04-29 04:11:29.234 [main] MyClass - Polling got records: 500
[INFO ] 2018-04-29 04:11:30.362 [I/O dispatcher 1] SUCCESS blablabla
[INFO ] 2018-04-29 xx:xx:xx.xxx [I/O dispatcher 2] SUCCESS blablabla
[INFO ] 2018-04-29 xx:xx:xx.xxx [I/O dispatcher 1] SUCCESS blablabla
[INFO ] 2018-04-29 xx:xx:xx.xxx [I/O dispatcher 1] SUCCESS blablabla
[INFO ] 2018-04-29 xx:xx:xx.xxx [I/O dispatcher 2] SUCCESS blablabla
...
...
[INFO ] 2018-04-29 06:28:35.003 [main] MyClass - Polling got records: 500
[INFO ] 2018-04-29 06:28:35.363 [I/O dispatcher 386] SUCCESS blablabla
[INFO ] 2018-04-29 xx:xx:xx.xxx [I/O dispatcher 385] SUCCESS blablabla
[INFO ] 2018-04-29 xx:xx:xx.xxx [I/O dispatcher 386] SUCCESS blablabla
[INFO ] 2018-04-29 xx:xx:xx.xxx [I/O dispatcher 385] SUCCESS blablabla
[INFO ] 2018-04-29 xx:xx:xx.xxx [I/O dispatcher 386] SUCCESS blablabla
...
[INFO ] 2018-04-29 06:31:35.003 [main] MyClass - Polling got records: 500
[INFO ] 2018-04-29 06:32:12.418 [I/O dispatcher 405] SUCCESS blablabla
[INFO ] 2018-04-29 xx:xx:xx.xxx [I/O dispatcher 406] SUCCESS blablabla
[INFO ] 2018-04-29 xx:xx:xx.xxx [I/O dispatcher 405] SUCCESS blablabla
[INFO ] 2018-04-29 xx:xx:xx.xxx [I/O dispatcher 406] SUCCESS blablabla
[INFO ] 2018-04-29 xx:xx:xx.xxx [I/O dispatcher 405] SUCCESS blablabla
...
[ERROR] 2018-04-29 xx:xx:xx.xxx [I/O dispatcher 405] FAILED blablabla! org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Connection closed unexpectedly
[ERROR] 2018-04-29 xx:xx:xx.xxx [I/O dispatcher 406] FAILED blablabla! org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Connection closed unexpectedly
// there the program stopped
```

Here is what I cannot understand:

1. Why for each 500 requests (response handling), there are only two I/O dispatchers? Is it because of the default setting of max 2?
2. Why the number of I/O dispatchers keep increasing for each 500 requests? Normally, what I experienced before is that, the number of I/O dispatcher will increase by but will also decrease back to 1 and 2. What I assume is that: it will reuse some of the previous I/O dispatchers, instead of every time creating new ones.
3. Why ConnectionClosedException at the end? Is it because too many I/O dispatchers halting the program?

### Update

Thanks for Oleg's comments, I found out the continuously increasing number of I/O dispatchers is because every time I got data from Kafka, a new http client is created. Then, there will be lots fo idling clients occupying the IOs and resources. That is also why the program stopped.

I still have some questions remains:

1. What does the **number** of I/O dispatcher shown in the logs mean? Is it the number of different threads?
2. How can I control the max number of I/O dispatchers for one http client? is it by I/O dispatcher?
3. What is the difference between this number of I/O dispatchers vs number of connections?
4. How to estimate number of I/O dispatchers and number of connections I will need based on the machine on which I am running the program and the data throughput/size?

Comment: You are not creating a new instance of HttpAsyncClient every time, are you?

Comment: @oleg yes I am. I also just found this bug. The client has not been closed and new client is created. Then we got lots of idling clients. That's why the io dispatcher number is increasing. Thanks.

Comment: You _really, really_ ought to re-use the same instance of HttpAsyncClient for all logically related requests

Comment: @oleg I still have some questions: 1. what does the number of I/O dispatcher mean? is it the number of different threads? 2. how can I control the max number of I/O dispatchers for one http client? is it by `I/O dispatcher`? 3. What is the difference between this **number of io dispatcher** vs **number of connection**? Thanks !

Comment: Can you update your question and I will answer them all?

Comment: @oleg I added the updates. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It represents a thread name.
2. I/O reactor properties and behavior can be controlled with `IOReactorConfig`
3. A small number of I/O dispatchers manage a much greater number of connections.
4. Most likely one I/O dispatch thread per CPU core is a reasonable default for the greatest majority of applications and one ought to not change it.